# Generic Handler not receiving full query string

Tags: asp.net, handler, uploadify

I'm trying to pass some values from one .aspx page to an handler (.ashx).
I was doing this by using the session variable but i came to realize that this works badly on Firefox and Chrome and i abandoned that idea and decided to pass the values by query string.

I am setting the handler like this on the uploadify init function.

```
'uploader'  : 'js/uploadify.swf',
'script'    : 'UploadVarios.ashx?util_Id=' + $('#<%= util_Id.ClientID %>').val() + '&util_NomeColaborador=' + $('#<%= util_NomeColaborador.ClientID %>').val() + '&util_IdPosto=' + $('#<%= util_IdPosto.ClientID %>').val() + '&ValueEstadoUploadVarios=' + $('#<%= ValueEstadoUploadVarios.ClientID %>').val() ,
'cancelImg' : 'js/cancel.png',
...
```

However, when i try to access the query string on the handler, only the first parameter is avaliable (in this case util_Id).

[image: debug print screen]

I thought that there may be something wrong with the way i was concatenating the string so i made a little test and changed it to this:

```
'uploader'  : 'js/uploadify.swf',
'script'    : 'UploadVarios.ashx?id1=0&id2=0',
'cancelImg' : 'js/cancel.png',
...
```

And here is the result:

[image: second print screen from debug]

What am i doing wrong?

EDIT: added the full query string

[image]

Comment: Can you post the URL as seen by ASP.Net (i.e. `context.Request.Url.OriginalString`)

Comment: Have you used Fiddler to see what's actually being sent over the wire?

Comment: @Kragen: i edited the post and added it now. 
AakashM: No, i haven't (yet). In part because i never used something like that and am not that familiar with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a suggestion - try to encode your query string like below.

```
'uploader'  : 'js/uploadify.swf',
'script'    : 'UploadVarios.ashx%3fid1%3d0%26id2%3d0',
'cancelImg' : 'js/cancel.png',
```

Probably that'll do the trick. If not, you could always go for decoding it with `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` and get key-value collection with `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`

Comment: Yep, this solved the problem. Am i supposed to encode the string? If so, how can i do this (not manually i mean)?

Comment: You can use JavaScript's encodeURIComponent() to automate that encoding.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to solve the issue using what you suggested.